# The limit of a function with a horizontal gap

Tags: limits

I have the following function:
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} 
      x+2 & \text{if $x < -2$} \\
      x-2 & \text{if $x > 2$}
\end{cases}
$$
which the graph looks like

[image]

and the domain of the function is $(-\infty, -2)\cup (2, \infty)$.

($f(x)$ is not defined at $x = -2$ or $x = 2$)

My question is, does the limit $$\lim_{x\to0}f(x)$$
exist?

Comment: But $x=0$ belongs not to the domain!

Comment: I don’t think it matters if the value we’re approaching isn’t in the domain. For example, you can still find the limit of $\frac{x}{x}$ at $x = 0$, but $x = 0$ itself doesn’t belongs to the domain of $\frac{x}{x}$

Comment: You have graphed the function wrong. Also if the function is the one you define in the upper part of your question then the only $x$ that doesn't belong to the domain is $x=2$

Comment: Sorry it’s my mistake. I wrote the function wrong but the graph should be correct.

Answer (score 1):

If you meant limit as $x \to 2$ then the limit exists: $lim_{x \to 2} f(x)=0$. Limit as $x \to 0$ does not make sense since the function is not defined throughout some interval containing $0$.

Comment: The answer is plainly written in the post above. The limit at $0$ does not exist because the function is not defined there.

Comment: I am surprised that the function is not defined at x=2 (according to the OP), yet the limit exists! Also, the OP graph is not showing f(-2) correctly!

Comment: Definition of the limit as $x \to 2$ does  not involve the value at $x=2$.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't. Check the definition: for each $\epsilon > 0$ there has to be $\delta$ such that if $\lvert x - 0\rvert \le \delta$ then $\lvert f(x) - L\rvert \le \epsilon$. But for *any* $x$ in the range $-1$ to $1$ there isn't a value of $f$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quote about limits from Bartle's *Introduction to Real Analysis: Fourth Edition*

> In order for the idea of the limit of a function $f$ at a point $c$ to be meaningful, it is necessary that $f$ be defined at points near $c$. It need not be defined at the point $c$, but it should be defined at enough points close to $c$ to make the study interesting. (Page 103)

If you have heard if the term **cluster point** then it should be easy to tell that $0$ is not a cluster point of the domain. Thus the limit at $x=0$ in this case doesn't hold meaning, which is another way of saying that it doesn't exist.